# Converting Numeric to Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column which contains NUMERIC(5,2) data.  The data is representative of shift start times.  A few examples are 6.30, 10.30, 13.30 and 15.30.  What's the best way to convert this into a time so I can do time calculations against another field?  The other field is a datetime field.

Edit: The values represent times.  For example 6.30 = 06:30, 15.30 = 03:30 PM.

Comment: What do those values represent?

Comment: I don't suppose you have access to the DB Schema or could suggest using a [TIME field](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243(v=sql.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: @powerlord I appreciate the attempt at fixing the root cause, however, I'm doing outsourced reporting for a company using a third party vendors database.  So in this instance, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select dateadd(minute, floor(col) * 60 + (col % 1) * 100, 0)
```

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . It breaks the number into two parts, one for hours and one for minutes.  It converts each part to minutes and uses that to create the time.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `dot(.)` with `colon(:)` and compare against your time column.

```
select * 
from yourtable 
Where timecol = replace(numericcol,'.',':')
```

considering `timecol` is of datatype `time`, rhs will be implicitly converted to `time`.

Comment: `6.3` is converted to `6:03` rather than `6:30`.